# Using Hamachi messes up with the Pi's networking

Tags: ssh, raspbian-stretch, iptables

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running Raspbian Stretch with no problems since over a year. I recently tried install Hamachi from the official LogMeIn website, and connected it to my LogMeIn Hamachi network.

I use my Pi for self-hosting purposes and it serves as a proxy for other machiens on my network. As so, it needs to be acessible without Hamachi (and this part was perfectly working before). I have a domain and I used to SSH to my Pi using it.

This worked perfectly unless I tried to SSH into the Pi after having installed and configured Hamachi as described previously. I wasn't able to access it from outside my LAN and more concerning, the HTTP proxy wasn't working thus making my other services unavailable. I was able to log in using SSH within the Hamachi network, and I noticed (using `ip route`) that Hamachi has configured a default IP route through the `ham0` interface, which appears above my normal default route (through `wlan0`). I believe this is a part of the issue.

Is there a way to prevent Hamachi from creating a default route which has the priority over the usual "local router" default route ?

Comment: What is Hamachi?

Comment: A service used for instance as a peer VPN to connect devices together. May I suggest you would have a hard time providing me with efficient help if you don't know what Hamachi is ?

Comment: It is good practice here to present a link to not well known applications for reference and for information so people can decide if they have enough knowledge. Maybe there are plain edge conditions that have to fit?